# Expected symmetry in the diophantine approximations of an irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-approximation

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we will write $\{x\}$ for the fractional part of $x$ and $\|x\|$ for the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer, in such a way that $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\|x\| = \min(\{x\}, 1 - \{x\})$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is, as usual, the greatest integer $\le x$.

Let $x$ be a fixed irrational number and $\mu$ its irrationality measure, namely the infimum of the set of all positive exponents $s$ such that

$$0 < \left|x - \frac{m}{n}\right| < \frac{1}{n^s}$$
for finitely many pairs $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}^+$. Assume that $\mu$ is finite (*added later: see N. Elkies' answer and the comments below*). Recall that $\mu \ge 2$ by (a corollary of) [Dirichlet's (approximation) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem). Then, given $s \in \{2\} \cup [2,\mu[$, define $G_s$ as the set

$$\{n \in \mathbb{N}^+: \|nx\| < n^{1-s}\},$$
and let $G_s^{-} := \big\{n \in G_s: \|nx\| = \{nx\}\big\}$ and $G_s^+ := G_s \setminus G_s^{-}$.

We have that $G_s$ is infinite (by Dirichlet's theorem and the definition of $\mu$), so at least one of $G_s^-$ or $G_s^+$ is infinite too, and I'm tempted to claim that *each* of them *must* be infinite. I don't have a serious argument in support of this: My only point is that it would be weird, I believe, to observe a similar "asymmetry" in the diophantine approximations of $x$ (yet, I would be happy to hear that my expectation is completely wrong). This leads to the following:

> > **Q1.** Is it true that $G_s^-$ is infinite for each $s \in \{2\} \cup [2,\mu[$? **Q2.** If Q1 is well-established, would you kindly provide me with a reference?

Some remarks: (i) If the answer to Q1 is yes, then it is as well true that $G_s^+$ is infinite for each $s \in \{2\} \cup [2,\mu[$. (ii) I can prove that the answer to Q1 is positive if $s = 2$ (this follows from Dirichlet's theorem and some elementary properties of the simple continued fraction expansion of $x$). (iii) By (ii) and [Khintchine's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_theorem_on_Diophantine_approximations#Khinchin.27s_theorem_and_extensions) (which yields that the irrationality measure of most real numbers is equal to $2$), the answer to Q1 is yes for almost all $x$.

Comment: What if the partial quotients in the continued fraction for $x$ alternate between big and small? Would that cause an asymmetry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be right in general.  For example
$$
x = 0.101000001000000000000000001\ldots
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 10^{-3^k}
$$
has plenty of lower approximants with exponent just under 3
(the partial sums) but no upper ones.

Comment: [I wanted to extend the decimal expansion to 81 digits
but that made it too wide.]

Comment: Right. And the irrationality measure of your $x$ is $3$ (and not $\infty$ as I had previously commented in a hurry).

Comment: Do you have a proof that there are no upper ones? I think defining $x$ through its continued fraction may be more tractable, say $x=[0;10,1,100,1,1000,1,\dots]$.

Comment: The lower approximants with $\mu \rightarrow 3$ have denominators that are
spaced close enough that there can't be any upper approximants with
$\mu$ much larger than $2$ (by the usual argument with 
$|p/q - p'/q'| \geq 1/qq'$).